# Cannot run Scala through ProcessBuilder

Tags: eclipse, scala, command-line

When I try to run

```
processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("scala", "-classpath", CLASSPATH, CLASSNAME);
process = processBuilder.start;
process.waitFor;
```

within an Scala application on Eclipse Helios IDE, it yields the

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "scala": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I've already configured the Windows system environment variable Path and scala runs OK on Windows command line. I've also added the variable Path into Eclipse run configuration.

Comment: 1. Does `CLASSPATH` contain any spaces? 2. What happens if you give full path to `scala` as the first argument?

Comment: 1. Yes
2. It runs if I specify the path to scala.bat clearly

Comment: Check the value returned from `processBuilder.environment().get("Path")`. Does it contain the directory with `scala.bat`?

Comment: Yes. But when I changed the directory to the new path without spaces, it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem here is that you need to pass `scala.bat`, not `scala`. To narrow down the problem, you should try running other programs, to see what you can or cannot run.

Comment: It works well with
    processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-version")

Comment: @classicalist Does it work with another executable in the same directory as `scala.bat`? Does it work with another `.bat` file in the same directory as `java.exe` (when passed without the extension)? Does it work with `scala.bat`?

Comment: .exe (without the extension) in same directory as scala.bat -> NO
.bat in same directory as java.exe -> NO
scala.bat -> YES

Now I see it works with extension included, except for "java"

Comment: @classicalist I find it very curious that the `exe` in the same directory as `scala.bat` did not work, but calling `scala.bat` did work. I had observed before that batch files seem to require the extension to be executed, but I can't figure out why `java` works but another exe doesn't, unless the `scala.bat` being called is not in the directory you think it is. You could put some `echo` for debugging in it, to be sure.

Comment: I have only 1 scala.bat on my system. The other .exe initially in java directory (like javacpl for example) work just fine. But a new one that I put into that doesn't. Thankyou very much for your concern.